# Bootstrap popover style issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Im make bootstrap `popover`,  i had some issue , ly list are inline , i dont want to show inline list,look my 2 images you can understand it
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/281xzffp/) my `code part` is its not working, but `fiddle` is working what happen?
**image 01- i need like this**

[image]

**actually my current working sample**

[image]

**html**

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" title="Bill Category">
       <input class="form-control input-sm" id="category" type="text" placeholder="Select category">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Description" type="text" placeholder="Description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Date" type="text" placeholder="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Paidby" type="text" placeholder="Paid by">
  </div>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>

<!-- loaded popover content -->
<div id="popover-content" style="display: none">
  <ul class="list-group custom-popover">
    <li class="list-group-item">Airport Pickup</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Food and Beverage</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Yoga Class</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1060;
    display: none;
    max-width: 276px;
    padding: 1px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    line-break: auto;
}
.popover-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-popover li {
  border: none!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-popover li:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important;
}

.custom-popover li:last-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  });
});
```

how to make like this **image 01**, please help me to fix this

Comment: Seem to working as expected/asked here --- https://jsfiddle.net/apuazy88/

Comment: sir, look im updated my question,its working `jsfiddle`, but not work `my application`

Comment: We cannot debug your application. You need to reproduce issue in fiddle. There might be some other css class which is overriding css class for li element.

Comment: ok sir, i'll check it

Answer (score 0):

Line height should be given in px. Try also specify width for li elementy because by default they are as small as they can so ale three of them fit in one line

Comment: Try changing max-width, to width in .popover, and width: 276px; in .custom-popover li